# create bootle disk copy of existing windows installation

Tags: windows, backup, images, iso-image

I have a fresh install of Windows will all my software nicely setup. I want to create a bootable ssd and copy the boot drive to it so I can boot from it later if I need to reinstall windows - as I frequently do!

Nothing I've seen on the net seems to do this. I assume that firstly I need to create an ISO of my C: drive in its entirety.

Then find a utility that will use that ISO and create a bootable hard drive (not a USB or CD). But none seem to recognise a hard drive for output.

Or ideally a utility that will do it all for me!

Please note I've looked at Win10's create an image utility which creates a series of folders but not an ISO. Their Media Creation tool is also no good. anyway I use Rufus for that but it only sources ED or ISO files!

Comment: As you state, I've only seen a two-step solution, e.g use a third-party tool such as Macrium Reflect to a) create a backup of Windows system files (or a complete disk  image), and b) create a small rescue USB or disk with an OS (WinPE) and the tool to restore the image from a). Some tools, such as DriveImage XML, use Linux on the rescue media, but work the same.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used Macrium to image my working system and Rufus to make an old  SATA drive bootable.

Comment: This is a pretty short answer. You yourself may know what you did but someone viewing this answer wouldn't know what to do. Can you please list the steps you followed for others who may run into this issue?